# Android: Retrofit: How to do lots of async requests correctly

Tags: java, android, http, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit 2.x in my Android client. In my special situation, I want to upload >500 picture objects (actually Files) asynchronically.

If the pictureList size is <50, then uploading all these files is no problem.

```
   for (Picture pic : pictureList) {
        uploadPictureAsync(pic)
```

But when the size goes over 100, my test device is aborting with the following error message:

> Large object allocation failed: ashmem_create_region failed for 'large
>   object space allocation': Too many open files

This seems to be caused by too many async requests.

The question is now: How can I handle such a huge amount of requests?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm currently doing something similar. I think I'm gonna have to create asynctasks on the callback methods of each asynctask

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I think the problem was that I pushed all requests at the same time in multiple AsyncTask instances, which was just too much for the device. So I changed it (IntentService instead of AsyncTask meanwhile) to upload one file - Wait for the response - When response arrived, upload the next file. So it's no more parallel, it's sequential now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that you have a single instance of your Retrofit service, if you use it, (instead doing lazy instantiation every time you need to do a call), either you will get "Too many open files" error.

Later, if you need to upload this quantity of images, I recommend you follow Android documentation about ThreadPoolExecutors to manage Async calls within the use of BlockingQueue.

https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/create-threadpool.html